# SAP Web Service PHP SoapClient input parameters

Tags: php, soap

I need to consume/call a SAP Web Service using PHP SoapClient. I am having trouble building the SOAP XML input parameters for the function that gets called, this is the example of the structure that is expected:

```xml
<xmii:XacuteRequest>
    <xmii:InputPar>
        <xmii:DATAINPUT>
            <![CDATA[<DATA><item><OBJECTID>1001</OBJECTID><OBJECTITEM/><FIELDNAME/><FIELDVALUE/></item></DATA>]]>
        </xmii:DATAINPUT>
        <xmii:TRANS>GETNAME</xmii:TRANS>
    </xmii:InputPar>
</xmii:XacuteRequest>
```

The parameters I need to give values to is `OBJECTID` and `TRANS`. I am having trouble with `OBJECTID`.

If I do `$soapclient->__getTypes();` I get this:

```php
    struct InputPar {
        string DATAINPUT;
        string TRANS;
    }
    
    struct XacuteRequest {
        InputParams InputPar;
    }
```

This is what my current array looks like:

```php
$params = array('InputPar' => array( array('DATAINPUT' => array('DATA' => array( 'item' => array('OBJECTID' => '1001') ) )),
             'TRANS' => 'GETNAME'
)
```

When I execute this I do get a response back with "Customer not found" with no errors. This tells me that everything is working correctly but `OBJECTID` is not being picked up. Also if I change `TRANS` to 'xxx' I do not get the "Customer not found" response telling me that `TRANS` is correctly being picked up.

So my only question is how do I structure may array so that `OBJECTID` is being recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the solution for those having the same issue.

So even though DATAINPUT is clearly an array, the thing to notice is:

```
<![CDATA[]]
```

CDATA means, Character Data, CDATA is defined as blocks of text. This is to allow XML characters in a string.

So whenever you see your tags are inside CDATA, in PHP SoapClient you have to declare that in a specific way as normally the XML tags will be escaped and I need the string to be exactly as is.

I had to create a new SoapVar, thats part of the SoapClient class, containing the string and importantly the XSD_ANYXML parameter. I did it this way:

```
$xmlContent = "<DATA><item><OBJECTID>1001</OBJECTID><OBJECTITEM/><FIELDNAME/><FIELDVALUE/></item></DATA>";

$tag = new SoapVar("<DATAINPUT><![CDATA[{$xmlContent}]]></DATAINPUT>", XSD_ANYXML);

$params = array('InputParams' => array(
        'DATAINPUT' => $tag,
        'TRANS' => 'GETNAME'
    )
);
```

You may notice that  is in the $tag variable and again in the $params array. I am not sure why but it did not work if I removed it from the $tag variable.

a SoapClient function that helped a lot to see the structure of what gets sent is $soapclient->__getLastRequest(). Call this after you send the xml.

```
echo '<pre>';
echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities(str_ireplace('><', ">\n<", $soapclient->__getLastRequest())) . "\n";
echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to use __getLastRequest() be sure to set "trace" to 1 when creating your soapclient like this:

```
$option=array('trace'=>1);
$soapclient = new SoapClient($url, $option);
```